# Mocha test fail in run, but succeed in debug mode

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, v8

I've a mocha test which succeeds when I run it in debug mode, but fails in run mode (I'm using WebStorm).

what I've done in the test is:

```
it("test messenger", function(done){
    messenger.send(message, callback); 
    //the messenger will save messages temporarily
    //and send them to outside message queue(nsq) every 1 second (using setInterval)

    reader.connect(nsq)... ; 

    reader.on('message', function(message){
        //validate message ...
        done();
    });
})
```

in Run mode, it always timeout, which means the read callback was not triggered, but in debug mode it succeeds...

If I schedule the receive code in a timeout, it will succeed in run mode:

```
it("test messenger", function(done){
    messenger.send(message, callback); 
    //the messenger will save messages temporarily
    //and send them to outside message queue(nsq) every second (using setInterval)
    setTimeout(function(){
        reader.connect(nsq)
        reader.on('message', function(message){
        //validate message ...
        done();
    }, 1000)

    });
})
```

My guess is that mocha will stuck in some place spinning, so the callback event has no chance to get executed, but in debug mode, somehow it's triggered.

Questions:

1. is my guess correct?
2. how could I find the spinning code in mocha? I've run mocha with --prof option, and use chrome `chrome://tracing` to load the profiling, but I've no idea how to find the place.

attached is the V8 log file [log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lkiversonlk/96244cb46d31f063df3efffd838c1849/raw/1b7df45beb585fa57f22d70a1b3208deaa4724fb/v8-mocha.log)

Answer (score 0):

Mocha doesn't spin, it wait's for the `done()` callback to be called.

It appears you have an issue with your queue or reader. Maybe the `message` event doesn't fire when you attach a reader to an empty queue or before a message arrives? Stepping through in debug or adding the delay would allow it to connect to an already populated queue.

You should be able to put a break point on whatever generates the `reader` `message` event to see if/when it fires in both scenarios.

Comment: in run mode the event was not fired, but in debug mode it fired. Even if the queue is empty when reader connect, the latter send message should fire the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause:

if only nsqlookupd provided, the nsq.js read client will poll the nsqlookupd server every 20 seconds to find available nsqd, so when the read client connect, there is no nsqd with specified topic currently, after write client sends message to the nsqd server, the read client's message handler should be fired 20 seconds later, so the mocha timeout.

in debug mode, the test runs so slow that 20 seconds passed, and the reader will go to lookupd server again and find the updated nsqd server with specified message...